# Embedded Signing API: Captive Recipients

Tags: docusignapi

Using embedded signing: when a captive recipient attempts to sign their *first* contract, they are presented with a dialog to 'agree to docusign terms and select signature'.

After terms are agreed to and the signature is selected, contract signing may proceed.

I am interested in learning if there is a way to set up the "captive recipient" account ahead of time.  So when the user goes to sign their first contract they are **NOT** presented the 'agree to terms' dialog.

We are thinking of making the docusign 'agree to terms and select signature' part of a different work flow in our application.

Does the API support this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are after is making the signature process a lot more integrated and having less things for user to click when they are going through the embedded flow, correct?

You can't really set up an account ahead of time but here are some things you can do:

1) you can configure your account (in demo or production) to not require a consumer disclosure.  I need to caution you that consumer disclosure and agreement to do business electronically is a part of the law, but maybe in your case it makes sense not to have it.  For instance I have seen many software packages roll in the consent to do business electronically into their main EULA.

2) You can preselect the font, style and the exact spelling of the signature through the API so people don't have to worry about selecting that which will streamline it even more.

3) as you already know the consequent signing sessions do not go through those screens as long as you keep the name, email and client userId the same.

Hope this helps and keep the questions coming!

-mb